# Tinker Kit 2 axis gyro unknown sensitivity

Tags: hardware-interface

I am reading the Tinker Kit 2 axis gyro (http://www.tinkerkit.com/gyroscope-4x/) with the ADC of my Atemga8. I am not using an arduino board nor am I using the tinker kit shield for the interfacing of the sensor board.

The datasheet of the gyro (LPR5150AL), which is mounted on the Tinker Kit claims the sensitivity to be either 0.67 or 0.167 mV/deg/sec depending on whether the output is amplified or not. Futhermore, it claims the zero-rate level to be 1.23 volts. When I read the output of the Tinker Kit when it is at rest I get a voltage around 2.5 Volts. I guess that the board internally converts the voltages. Can anybody now tell me what the correct sensitivity is because if I use the ones indicated in the datasheet I get wrong results e.g. the angular velocity is way too high. I tried to correct the sensitivity with the ratio of the upper named voltages (correction_factor = 2.5/1.23). Now the results are  more plausible but I want to make sure if this is correct and if not what is the correct sensitivity?

Thanks in advance!
Roman

Comment: I'm having the same problems. Did you find a solution? Data seems available for the gyroscope, but not for the Tinkerkit Shield. Do you know about wiring?